# Flexslider 2 is not displaying the images in IE7

Tags: jquery, css, flexslider

I'm using the FLexslider 2 and It works well in all the browsers except IE7. In IE7, images are not loading and I can see only the arrows to navigate.

This is how I initialize the plugin,

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
               animation: "slide",              //Select your animation type (fade/slide)
               slideshow: true,                //Should the slider animate automatically by default? (true/false)
               slideshowSpeed: 7000,           //Set the speed of the slideshow cycling, in milliseconds
               animationDuration: 500,         //Set the speed of animations, in milliseconds
               directionNav: true,             //Create navigation for previous/next navigation? (true/false)
               controlNav: true,               //Create navigation for paging control of each clide? (true/false)
               keyboardNav: true,              //Allow for keyboard navigation using left/right keys (true/false)
               touchSwipe: true,               //Touch swipe gestures for left/right slide navigation (true/false)
               prevText: "Previous",           //Set the text for the "previous" directionNav item
               nextText: "Next",               //Set the text for the "next" directionNav item
               randomize: false,                //Randomize slide order on page load? (true/false)
               slideToStart: 0,                //The slide that the slider should start on. Array notation (0 = first slide)
               pauseOnAction: true,            //Pause the slideshow when interacting with control elements, highly recommended. (true/false)
               pauseOnHover: false,            //Pause the slideshow when hovering over slider, then resume when no longer hovering (true/false)
               controlsContainer: ".flexslider-container"           //Advanced property: Can declare which container the navigation elements should be appended too. Default container is the flexSlider element. Example use would be ".flexslider-container", "#container", etc. If the given element is not found, the default action will be taken.
           });
```

Other than this I'm using the default CSS and HTML without any changes. I would appreciate if anyone can help me fix this.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Share the link. If their (woothemes/madebymuffin) works in IE7, then it's likely something else on your page. Are you testing this on an actual machine in IE7 or on browser stack or something?

Comment: I'm using the IE10's browser stack.

Comment: Gotta share a link to your issue. But you can't be using the default css if you have your own container. IE 7 has hacks you need such as zoom:1 and other things (depending on the situation) to make things show up.